# Python read pickle file and wait when empty

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

Basically I am using pickle in the simplest way possible. I have a code that fills data it receives in a pickle file, that is read by another code to submit a command.

Unfortunately, when there is no data (waiting), the reading stops with the following :

```
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I want it to wait for new data to come without closing the file and stoping the read process, I played with different conditions in my code but not working. So I am thinking of doing this :

```
dbfile = open('examplePickle', 'rb')
while True:
   CHECK IF FILE EMPTY 
   IF YES : WAIT TILL NOT
   IF NOT : DO THE READING AND ALL
```

However I don't seem to find how to do that, any help please ? or maybe better suggestions/clues ?
Thanks.